# Upper bound on r* on page 7 in the Scale Invariant Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers paper

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I was hoping to get some clarification on how the bound on r* was calculated (bottom of [page #7](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/032.pdf)). I'm trying to reproduce the results that have been shown, however I keep getting a slightly smaller bound for r* . It would be really helpful if anyone could tell me which components were added from the previous equation to get r* .

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to know how the authors found the inequality $|r^*| \leq 2^{\rho' - n + 3}$ ?

Comment: I've managed to figure out the bound on |r*| but now I'm stuck on how |q3| <= theta is calculated. I understand that q3 = q1+ q2, but I'm not sure how to calculate the bound on q1 and q2 to begin with.

Comment: @Vitor any help with how to calculate the bound on q3 would be greatly appreciated!